# how to create header php footer php or sidebar.php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

ok. i want create a php file. i want make header.php footer.php. i need it because it will make me not tried to edit one by one in html. how to do that.? thank in advance answer soon ! :v

```css
footer{ text-align:center; margin-top: 150px;}
ul{list-style-type: none;}
a {text-decoration: none; color: green;}
li a,li {padding: 0px 10px;}
```

```html
<!---Header--->

<ul class="navbar">
 <li><a href="#">navbar</a>
 <a href="#">navbar</a>
 <a href="#">navbar</a>
 <a href="#">navbar</a>
 <a href="#">navbar</a></li>
</ul>

<!----footer--->

<footer class="w3-container w3-green">
 <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</footer>
```

Comment: You can simply [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) other files in your scripts.

Comment: You can include php files at different location and the file including it must be php as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create the file header.php and use the [get_header()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) function to include it in your index.php. To include your footer.php you can use the [get_footer()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer) function.

**header.php**

```
<!---Header--->

<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">navbar</a>
    <a href="#">navbar</a>
    <a href="#">navbar</a>
    <a href="#">navbar</a>
    <a href="#">navbar</a></li>
</ul>
```

**footer.php**

```
<!----footer--->

<footer class="w3-container w3-green">
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</footer>
```

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<main>Main content</main>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

use php's include_once.

First, put your header and footer contents in a header.php and footer.php file.

**Header.php**

```
   <ul class="navbar">
      <li>
         <a href="#">navbar</a>
         <a href="#">navbar</a>
         <a href="#">navbar</a>
         <a href="#">navbar</a>
         <a href="#">navbar</a>
      </li>
   </ul>
```

**Footer.php**

```
   <footer class="w3-container w3-green">
      <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
   </footer>
```

Then in your main php files, let's say it's index.php, you can do it this way.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html>
      <head>
         blablabla
      </head>
      <body>
         <!--Header-->
         <?php include_once 'path-to-header.php'; ?>
         Another body contents
         <!--Footer-->
         <?php include_once 'path-to-footer.php'; ?>
      </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create header.html and footer.html:

header.html:

```
<ul class="navbar">
    <li><a href="#">navbar</a>
    <a href="#">navbar</a>
    <a href="#">navbar</a>
    <a href="#">navbar</a>
    <a href="#">navbar</a></li>
</ul>
```

footer.html:

```
<footer class="w3-container w3-green">
    <p>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</p>
</footer>
```

Whenever you want to include either of the two code in a portion of your code, paste the following:

For the header:

```
<?php require('header.php'); ?>
```

For the footer:

```
<?php require('footer.php'); ?>
```

Whenever you want to edit the style of your header/footer, just go into those files and create the styles you wish. Alternatively you can link a css file to the files.